# Create Docker nginx but browser returns site not found error

Tags: windows, nginx, docker

Windows 11 Pro

I'm following the Hashicorp Terraform Docker tutorial :

```
$ docker run --name hashicorp-learn --detach --publish 8080:80 nginx:latest
dc26543abdf895e638e4c5fcb968a9ce317c57e945060e97afe03b3991646682

$ docker ps --filter="name=hashicorp-learn"
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                  NAMES
dc26543abdf8   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   28 seconds ago   Up 27 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   hashicorp-learn
```

Everything seems ok but when I open browser and go to

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

I get error

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

I've tried this in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and receive similar errors.

I've tried switching off internal/external Windows Defender Firewall but still receive error.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a usable IP address. **On docker host use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/`** (as a weird hack you can also do `http://127.1:8080/`). From any _other_ machine you must use an actual address or resolvable name of the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0:8080 that you see in docker ps output does not mean you should browse to this address, it means that your server is listening on all of it's ip addresses on port 8080 so you should go to

```
http://server_ip:8080
```

or you can test this on your docker server by running

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
```